# Syntax for POST request

Tags: http, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to make a POST request to the following url: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/signup

However I get this response:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/signup?first_name=&last_name=&email_id=&password=&dob ...Please pass parameters...

So I tried making the request like this:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/signup?first_name=Jay&last_name=Last&email_id=Jay@test.com&password=qqq&dob=1/1/15

But I get the same response.

I have no idea what the correct syntax is supposed to be...

Can someone please explain how I should rewrite the url?

**Edit**
After I make the request, if successful, I get a response saying "success new user" and a JSON with the key/vals

Comment: When you use a post request you have to put the values in the request Body. Not in the URL.

Comment: @Jens you don't _have_ to. It depends on how the service is implemented... So OP: _"I have no idea what the correct syntax is supposed to be..."_ - look at the documentation for the service.

Comment: Ya in this service they put the values in the url for some reason. I just can't get the syntax

Comment: Try url encoding  your variables.  since the `@` and the  `/` can cause issues depending upon the way the endpoint is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does encoding your values make any difference?

for example:

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/signup?first_name=Jay&last_name=Last&email_id=Jay%40test.com&password=qqq&dob=1%2F1%2F15`